How to plot train and test losses of imbalanced binary NN model
I am trying to plot train and test loss of my imbalanced binary classification NN model.
Could you tell me what should I add to plot them? Or could you provide other sources that I can check?
One more thing, It seems loss does not decrease much.
For example, loss keeps changing between 0.90 and 0.50 without showing clear decreasing trend over epoch.
I started to do it just yesterday...
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader, WeightedRandomSampler

class ImbalancedDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data, targets):
        self.data = data
        self.targets = targets

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.data[idx], self.targets[idx]

# Load CSV file into a Pandas DataFrame
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('E:/myCodes/R_projects/paper/binary.csv')

# Assuming the last column is the target variable
data = df.iloc[:, 9:30].values
targets = df.iloc[:, 1:2].values

data = torch.from_numpy(data)
targets = torch.from_numpy(targets)
dataset = ImbalancedDataset(data, targets)

##
class_sample_count = torch.tensor([(targets == t).sum() for t in torch.unique(targets)])
weight = 1. / class_sample_count.float()
samples_weight = torch.tensor([weight[int(t)] for t in targets])

sampler = WeightedRandomSampler(samples_weight, len(samples_weight))

train_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=64, sampler=sampler)

import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

class SimpleNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SimpleNN, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(21, 50)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(50, 2)
        self.double()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x

model = SimpleNN()
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

num_epochs = 100

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for inputs, labels in train_loader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels.long().squeeze()) # fix 
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}, Loss: {loss.item()}')

